# Navfree required space

Tags: storage, navigation

I was wondering how much space [Navfree](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navfree.android.OSM.ALL&hl=nl) needs for its maps. I know it depends on what parts of the world you download, so is there any place I can check it, other than the app itself? (Alternatively how much does it take to download the entire world, Europe and France for instance.)

(Note: I think this is a good place to ask this? Couldn't find where it would be asked better, please tell if I'm wrong and I'll move it.)

Answer (score 1):

As you had said yourself, the maps size can be known only when you start to download.  The app itself takes approx 20Mb (Total size = App size + data) and it includes no map (actually app will say installing `World map`, but unless you download a country's map you wouldn't be see anything on screen that resembles a map).

Map for France:

[image: Map for France]
You might also be interested to download other stuffs other than map. For instance for UK, you can download postcode database which can be very useful for locating a destination without Internet connection. Also, it would be worth while to download speed cameras database so that you would get a warning when you approach one and warn if your current speed is high to cause you trouble.